# How to remove missing plugin error while using embed tag

Tags: html, video, embed

As I am using embed tag in my html file but in browser it is showing missing plugin. To solve this plugin problem what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For playing FLV in html, you should use the  tag. For example:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
width="320" height="240" 
wmode="transparent" 
data="player.swf?file=video.flv&autoStart=false">
<param name="movie" 
value="player.swf?file=video.flv&autoStart=false"/>
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
</object>
```

Player.swf is player swf file and filename is the file attribute.